# WAMP Server not turning green every time I restart my Surface

Tags: wamp, wampserver

[image][image]I've been using WAMP server for a few of my school projects however I have had a lot of trouble with it staying green. I am pretty sure its an internal issue but I'm not really sure how to figure out what exactly is happening. The main problem I experience is that it installs fine and runs. However, whenever I restart my laptop it will not turn green. It stays orange and says 1 of 2 services running. I tried the methods I saw online however it does not even let me right-click it to see what isn't running or to restart the services. I've had to reinstall it about five times to keep using it and it's getting extremely annoying. I think it has to do with mySQL not starting properly but then why do I not get the option to right click?

Comment: Sounds like you may have missed the initial dialog on the install that say you need to make sure you have all the MSVC Runtimes installed. Download this [checker tool from the WAMPServer guys](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/tools/check_vcredist.exe) run it and it will tell you which, if any, MSVC Runtimes you nare missing

Comment: Hi! I have posted a picture of the error, but I thought I had all of MSVC 2008 downloaded

Comment: THe image says it all. So the solution is to install all the missing MSVC runtimes until that utility reports none missing

Answer (score 0):

check if you have any previous installations ( for example : mysql,MariaDB ..ect ) and open task manager and see the proccess of mysql ( open the properties ) if the path isn't from the wamp mysql then desactivate it / kill the process.

here's FAQ ***[Link](https://superuser.com/questions/321744/wamp-mysql-service-will-not-start)*** that helped me alot in the past , you may find it usefull